# If you could ask Walter Murch one question (or piece of advice), what would it be?

Tags: sound-design, film

What would you ask Walter Murch if you had a chance? But just one question! Look forward to seeing some answers :)

Cheers!

Comment: Should I get my hopes up and wonder if TheSoundMonster is really Walter? Did Andrew Spitz negotiate a special Q & A thread with Walter on SSD? Ooo the possibilities.

Comment: Nice try, Walter Murch.

Comment: @Utopia Dream on...

Comment: @thesoundmonster... When do we get to read the article?

Answer (score 3):

Can you apprentice me for 2 years on video editing and sound design?

Comment: haha...i like!!!

Comment: I'll second that!!

Answer (score 2):

What is the best mistake you ever made?

Comment: I thought of asking him for all his money, and then I thought about asking him to let me be his roommate... Then I realized that these were all yes or no questions that may not ultimately pay off. But learning from a mistake, now that'll be a lesson for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Would you like an assistant?

Comment: Love this question!

Answer (score 1):

One question? That's all I get?

Would you edit my next film?

Answer (score 1):

Can I have coffee with you and just talk and talk and talk and talk........?

Answer (score 1):

"Seeing as you apparently have more brilliant thoughts, ideas, and analogies before lunchtime than the average person has in a year, would you please join Twitter?"

Comment: Incidentally, a Twitter people search for Walter turns this up:

http://img.ly/system/uploads/001/042/410/large_bieber.png?1306219805

Answer (score 1):

My friend liases with him through email quite a bit as he is tech support for hardware he has used on a film, I've been tempted.

Answer (score 1):

dude! can we trade places? -then wake up~!

Answer (score 1):

I'd be seconding "oinkaudio", can we just go for a coffee and talk for hours? I'll need to make notes... :)

Seriously though, the guy is a true inspiration. Just amazing, we all owe a lot to Walter Murch!

Answer (score 1):

What was it that made your most challenging project so difficult?

Answer (score 1):

If you had one film/project to do over again, which one would it be?  Why?

Answer (score 1):

How much of your career/work/innovation/success is the result of happenstance/luck and how much the result of hard work and dedication?

Answer (score 1):

Do you find that current collaborators tend to acquiesce too easily and assume that you must be right because of the weight of your CV?

Comment: @g.a.harry - I like this question. It's something I've often wondered about many people (even myself) in many different situations. Not necessarily because of the CV weight, but because of a whole plethora of dynamics that might invoke such a situation.

Comment: @syndicate, Totally. I am a big fan of micro-anthropology. Societies in and of themselves are kind of boring, but the nuances of interpersonal power struggles I find fascinating. 

Answer (score 0):

Throughout the rest of the production process, great care is taken to ensure that the characters portrayed on screen are meaningful, believable, and compelling; how do you think about and approach the art of sound composition with regard to those ends?  By which I mean:

1) To what degree do you treat sound as an aid to the actors' portrayal of character (i.e. supporting the suspension of disbelief).
2) To what degree do you consider the sound as a character unto itself.

Do you ever find these two elements to be in conflict with each other?

Answer (score 0):

where did you lose your wallet last time?

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Murch, what words of advice would you give to all those students who are taking their first steps into the fascinating and overwhelming world of Sound Design?

Answer (score 0):

What's your source of inspiration that makes you create something different in every project?